# Hangfire: Set end time for recurring job

Tags: c#, .net, cron, expression, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire for jobs.

I have a function need run between two moment.

EX: Start time: 8:13
End time: 21:32
Interval: 15 minutes.

Run everyday.

What is the "expression" for this requirement?

Comment: maybe you need to make a cron expression for that.. im not sure if it was already define.

Answer (score 7):

Hangfire uses cron(tab) notation.

You'll need to add the task three times:

```
13-59/15 8 * * *
*/15 9-20 * * *
0-32/15 21 * * *
```

Using it:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("MyJob!"), "13-59/15 8 * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("MyJob!"), "*/15 9-20 * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("MyJob!"), "0-32/15 21 * * *");
```

First line says between the minutes of 13 and 59, for hour 8, run every 15 minutes.

Second line says for the hours 9 - 20, run every 15 minutes

Third line says for the minutes 0-32, for hour 21, run every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, but this do not requirement. My job is run on: 

8:13-8:28..........and stop interval when 21:32

Comment: One expression for this, it is possible?

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware it's not possible (it's not possible in cron, either). Which part of the requirement doesn't it meet, exactly?

Comment: My job maybe run in 21:13 and 21:28 and Stop.
But:
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("MyJob!"), "0-32/15 21 * * *");=> run 21:00-21:15-21:30

And Job maybe run in: 9:13-9:28.. but
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("MyJob!"), "*/15 9-20 * * *");=> run 9:00-9:15....

Comment: Those results look correct, though - based on your original question. It runs every 15 minutes within the specified time period. Can you show me a time (just one) where it runs but shouldn't?